# Solve trigonometric equation with maple

Tags: trigonometry

Let $b(q)$ be given by

[expression b(q)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prysl.png)

Find $\alpha$ such that b(q) = 0.
By hand, we can find the solution 
$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{2}atan(\frac{2\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)}{sin^2(\theta_2)-\sin(\theta_1)^2})
$$

But maple find $atan(\frac{\sin(\theta_2)}{\sin(\theta_1)})$. What did he do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Divide the numerator & the denominator by $\sin^2\theta_2$ and put $\dfrac{\sin\theta_1}{\sin\theta_2}=\tan y$ to find

$$\arctan\frac{2\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)}{\sin^2(\theta_2)-\sin(\theta_1)^2}=\arctan(\tan 2y)$$

Now use from the Article $240,$ Ex$-5$ of [Plane Trigonometry(by Loney)](http://archive.org/details/planetrigonomet00lonegoog),

$$\arctan x+\arctan y=\begin{cases} \arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy} &\mbox{if } xy<1\\ \pi+\arctan\frac{x+y}{1-xy} & \mbox{if } xy>1\end{cases} $$

Comment: $$\arctan\frac{2\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)}{\sin^2(\theta_2)-\sin(\theta_1)^2}=2\arctan(\tan y)$$

Comment: it seems that the corrective term when the denominator is negative is $\pi/2$ instead of $\pi$